# About Riemann's Hypothesis.

Tags: riemann-hypothesis

Could Riemann' Hypothesis be proven true using Robin's Inequality and that a counter-example to Riemann's Hypothesis can not have a divisor that is a prime number to the exponent 5 ,according to some of Robin's Theories? Also I think it can be proven the product of two numbers A and B that are counter-examples to R.H. is also a counter-example. Note a number $n$ is a counter-example to R.H. if $\sigma(n)\gt e^{\gamma}n\ln\ln n$ (forgive notation).

Comment: Language remark: such an $n$ would not be a "counterexample to RH," it would be a counterexample to an equivalent to the RH. A counterexample to RH would be a nontrivial zero with real part off the critical line.

Comment: According to Lagharius ( forgive spelling) if R.H. is false for n then              (n) ≥ H + eᴴ  l n (H) , because H > l n ( n+1) ∴                                          (n) ≥ l n ( n+1) + ( n+1) l n( l n (n+1))  (∀ n > 1) If l n (l n ( n+1)) ≥ 3 then       ( n) ≥ 3(n+1) + l n ( n+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robin's inequality was proved to be true if the Riemann Hypothesis holds, so disproving Robin's inequality would be one way of disproving the Riemann Hypothesis. However, the inequality has been around for a long time (Ramanujan got the result in 1915), this is probably just as hard as any other way of settling the Riemann Hypothesis.

I am not quite sure what you mean by numbers that are counter-examples to the Riemann Hypothesis. The Hypothesis itself is about the complex zeros to a complex function (the claim is that the zeros with positive real part all have real part 1/2).

[Added later] Yes, Robin proved in 1984 that the inequality holding for all $n>5040$ is equivalent to the RH. So in principle you can disprove RH by finding a single integer which fails Robin's inequality. But thirty years later, no one has succeeded by that route.

[Added later] @user128932 Sorry, I failed to answer your point about $a,b$. So suppose $a,b$ (both $>5040$) failed to satisfy Robin's inequality, so that $\sigma(a)>e^\gamma a \ln\ln a$ and $\sigma(b)>e^\gamma b \ln\ln b$, does that mean $ab$ also fails to satisfy it?

$\sigma(n)$ is a "multiplicative function" which means (in this context) that $\sigma(mn)=\sigma(m)\sigma(n)$ provided that $m,n$ are relatively prime. So if $a,b$ were relatively prime exceptions, we would have $\sigma(ab)=\sigma(a)\sigma(b)>e^{2\gamma}(ab)(\ln\ln a)(\ln\ln b)$.

For $ab$ to be another exception we want $\sigma(ab)>e^\gamma ab\ln\ln(ab)$.
Now $e^\gamma>1.78$, so $e^{2\gamma}>1.78e^\gamma$, which is helpful. We have $\ln(a)\ln(b)>\ln(a)+\ln(b)=\ln(ab)$ for large $a,b$, which is also helpful, eg $\ln(5051)\ln(5059)=72.73>17.06=\ln(5051\cdot5059)$. Of course this effect is reduced for $\ln\ln$, eg $(\ln\ln 5051)(\ln\ln 5059)=4.59>2.84=\ln\ln(5051\cdot5059)$. But $(\ln\ln a)(\ln\ln b)>\ln\ln(ab)$ obviously holds in general for sufficiently large $a,b$ (and maybe for all $a,b$ I have not really thought about it).

So yes in the $a,b$ relatively prime case it looks as though $ab$ would be another exception. The case where they are not relatively prime looks more doubtful, eg $\sigma(16)=5<8=\sigma(2)\sigma(8)$.

Comment: Robin's inequality says if sigma(n) < $e^{gamma}$ n lnlnn for any n > 5040 then R.H. is true. ( I looked this up in this website) So if there exists m such that sigma(m) >= $e^{gamma}$ m lnlnm where m > 5040 then m could be 'called' a counter-example to R.H.; using this with the fact the product of two 'counter-example integers' is also a 'counter-example integer' maybe one can show such 'counter-examples' can't exist.

Comment: Actually, you can. RH is equivalent to universal statements about the integers. There is a thread on MO where this is discussed

Comment: @user128932 Thank you. Yes a single integer $m$ could be used to disprove RH. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Thank you ; I rarely get a response on these stack exchanges that says I might actually be right. Thank you..

Comment: What about the idea if a and b are two couterexamples to Robin's inequality and a and b are relatively prime then (a b) is a counterexample?

Comment: For any a,b such that lna,lnb >2 then lna lnb >lna +lnb =ln(a b) so ln(lna lnb) > lnln(a b); therefore lnlna + lnlnb > lnln(a b) so e^{gamma} lnlna + e^{gamma} lnlnb > e^{gamma} lnln (a b). IF a and b are counterexamples to Robin's inequality and (a b) is not then {sigma(a)}/a +{sigma(b)}/b > {sigma(a b)}/(a b). Also a and b must be not deficient numbers so sigma(a)/a , sigma(b)/b >2.  Also sigma(a)/a + sigma(b)/b < sigma(a) sigma(b) /(a b). So sigma(a) sigma(b) > sigma(a b). if a and b are coprime this is a contradiction. So if a, b are coprime and conterexamples then so is(a b).

Comment: @user128932 I will look at this later today (maybe in 6 hours or so - now 7:30am London UK time, and I am late running late for mass). Oh, can you fix the sigmas (the need a backslash in from of them and to be inside \$ ... \$ . Similarly for stuff like e^{gamma} which would then come out as $e^\gamma$. It is really hard to read as it is.

Comment: @user128932 I am not sure your argument is correct in all the details. For example, the first clause is not quite right, eg $\ln 3\ln3.5-\ln(3\times3.5)=-0.975$ - you need to push $a,b$ up a bit higher than 2. Similarly, I am not sure about your deficient condition. But in principle, yes. As, I said in the answer, I agree with you that if $a,b$ are coprime exceptions, then $ab$ is another exception, at least provided $a,b$ are sufficiently big. But that last caveat is unlikely to be significant. I imagine smallish exceptions have already been ruled out.

Comment: Note if a is a counterexample then sigma(a)/a >= e^{gamma} lnlna ; if a was deficient then 2 > sigma(a)/a , so 2 > e^{gamma} lnlna . So if one lets a > e^{e^2} and b > e^{e^2} then a and b can not be deficient counterexamples. Therefore if a and b > e^{e^2} and they are coprime counterexamples then so is (a b). Assume there is a least squarefree  C, that is not a counterexample; C = (a b) for some a and b (C > a, b > 1); a and b are coprime and both squarefree. Assume a is a counterexample then b can't be, yet if b is not a counterexample it is < C. This shows no counterexample is squarefree.

Comment: Sorry about the notation problems , I find this 'inputting' system difficult. Maybe these Stack exchange websites could have a special symbols virtual keyboard.

Comment: @user128932 It does take a bit of getting used to. But the basic idea is easy. Put symbols between a pair of dollar signs \$ ... \$. Use the backslash for "special words", such as sigma. So to get sigma(a) as $\sigma(a)$ you need "\$\ sigma(a)\$" (without the outer quotes). Sorry the spacing is slightly awry there, defeating the system is harder than using it! :)

Comment: Great info , but I wish these websites had a virtual keyboard. I have a bit of a learning problem ; I am sporadically hyperactive. I learn things 'better' with visual and creative expanations ; detailed instructions I find very taxing.

Comment: Does what I wrote above show no squarefree integer can be a counter example to Robin's Inequality??

Comment: That is a good question, which I cannot answer instantly. Why not ask it as a new question, then you might attract someone who could! Also I am hopelessly backlogged with work for the next 48 hours.

Comment: There is no rush for any answers , I'm just afraid if I have an important result I must get it verified or I won't get any benefits from it. That is a good suggestion about asking a new question.

Comment: If (n p) is a counterexample to robin's inequality and n is not ( p is prime and n a positive integer) then this implies in in(n p) ,

Comment: .. this implies in in(n)) < in (inn)^(3/2)  and p < n^(1/2) so if m is a counter example  and q is a prime > m^(1/2) then (m q) is a counterexample.

Comment: If m is a counter example to Robin's inequality and q is a prime > m^(1/2) then m times q is a counter example. This can show a counter example exists with q^5 as a divisor which Robin said couldn't exist, I think..

Comment: To rephrase the post on May 8 / 15 ; if (n p) is a counterexample to Robin's inequality and n  is not a counterexample ∴ (n p)/(n p) ≥ eᵞ l n l n (n p) and (n)/n < eᵞ l n l n (n) , if p  primes and p< √n so p²< n  if p|n then ( n p) =(n₁ pʳ) where p does not divide n ∴ (n p) =(n₁) ( pʳ) such that r≤ 2 ∴ ( n p) = ( n₁) ( p² +p + 1) or ( n p) = ( n₁) (p+1) ∴                  ( n p)/( n p) = ( n₁) (p + 1+ 1/p) ≥  (n₁) (p +1)  or                                     (n p) / (n p) = (n₁) ((p+1)/p) where p does not divide n₁

Comment: Also ( n₁ p) = (n) ∴ (n) /n =( (n₁)/n₁) ((p+1)/p)  so if r=2 then ( n p) / ( n p) ≥       (n) /n so if ( n p) is a counterexample and n is not and p primes  .      l n ( n p) ≥ l n (n) or so l n l n (n p) ≥ l n l n (n) ; eᵞ l n l n (n) ≥ (n)/n  and eᵞ l n l n (n p) < ( n p) this contradicts .∴ If (n p) is a counterexample and n is not  and p² < n this is a contradiction. So if (n p) is a counterexample and p² ≥ n then so is n.